# Images can be pushed outside the boundaries of a post by using nested lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, images, list

1. A

   1. B

      1. C

         1. D

            1. E

               1. F

                  1. [image]

I don't even know. It just seemed weird.

Yes, I understand I could just avoid doing something like that. But the problem already exists with a single level.

Consider having 2 images in a post. Both exceed the maximum width of a post. One is nested in a list. Key to this issue is that my original images were much larger. They were automatically resized.

#### Image

[image]

#### List

1. [image]

I think it looks weird.

Comment: So...don't do that?

Comment: @Bart: I added a more common case.

Comment: Hmm, well, perhaps this can be handled. As a user you can already do several things though. Imgur supports "m" or "s" at the end of the filename (before the .jpg or .png) to use a medium or small version. And there is [a StackApp](http://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader) which can help you with a thumbnail and even a link to the original format image. Though I've never needed to use the latter, so I don't know how useful that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed using **@animuson**'s suggestion:

> This could easily be fixed by using a `max-width: 100%;` on images

Three years is a long time to wait. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: most likely because there was a reminder yesterday ;) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323304/large-image-overflows-the-post-when-inside-a-blockquote/323387#323387

Answer (score 20):

This could easily be fixed by using a `max-width: 100%` on images rather than the current 640px.

> [image: Nested images with max width 100%]

Is there any specific reason why they opted to use an exact pixel size instead? If they're not going to change it, I might just add this style to my custom user styles because I think it actually makes the display of images better overall.

Comment: I'm using this in my user styles as well now. Works great :)

Comment: I've added your fix to the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.4. Thanks!

Comment: @animuson : `max-width:`don't work on some IE versions.

Comment: @user2284570: Do those "some IE versions" include any of the [supported ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)?

Comment: @user2284570 `max-width` has been supported since IE 7, so there's really not any worry there.

Comment: @animuson : Sorry for this explanation : Stack Exchange work with ie6 *(although officially not supported : I tried it)*. windows 98 SE = FF 2.0 =ie6 = opera 10 = Only way to play dos games who didn't wanted to use DirectX and used Dos for using privileged instructions and real mode (vm86 don't work) = Only way to get the sound on them with a recent card. I call windows ME a downgrade. Windows 98 itself can't run inside a virtual machine : it can't use vm86.

Comment: @user2284570 Stack Exchange *really* doesn't care about IE 6. It's not even supported by Microsoft anymore. Worst case is that IE 6 will ignore the property and the image will still overflow in that browser. No big deal.

Comment: Now that you're part of the team can you maybe use this to have your suggestion be implemented?

Comment: Repeating my previous comment. ^