# Make the quick-answer box wider

Tags: feature-request, design

## Before

[image]

## After

```
#post-form .wmd-container,
#post-form .wmd-input,
#post-form .wmd-preview {
  width : 720px;
}

#post-form .post-editor,
#post-form .wmd-button-bar {
  width : 728px;
}
```

[image]

I guess, it's debateable, but, I like it :)

Comment: Yeah, I kinda like that. It's subtle and doesn't change the existing layout, but would make the input box more useful.

Comment: Why use pixels as a unit and not percentages? Having a flexible layout would prove a 'quick win'. Having a responsive design would be totally awesome!

Comment: @MartindeKeijzer: I just don't know better. I'd be very happy to learn how to improve it :)

Comment: Well, the primary reason it's the size that it is is to make sure that the preview is (generally) representative of the final post. Note that the post voting controls take up that seemingly extra space once you hit submit.

Comment: @TimStone: If that was the reasoning, it wasn't sound. Due to Markdown formatting the size of the editing area isn't really an indication of the [width of the rendered output](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143973/images-can-be-pushed-outside-the-boundaries-of-a-post-by-using-nested-lists), if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Not the size of the editing area, but the size of the *preview* area, which in your mock-up has grown along with the text box itself. With a wider preview area, you might be tricked into thinking that a particular code block wasn't going to scroll, only to be unpleasantly surprised after posting. You could widen the text area without widening the preview panel, but the lack of consistency might be a bit off-putting.

Comment: @TimStone: Oh, right. Sorry about that. Yeah, that's really a problem. Maybe aligning the whole thing to the right might yield better results - functionally and visualy.