# Images in open source "roles" section can overflow container

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I include a large image in the "role" section of an open source project in Careers 2.0 - it overflows the container.

Looks like it is missing this CSS rule, because images in the "Experience" section are properly resized:

```
.cv div.cv-section .description img {
    max-width: 650px;
}
```

---

[image: image overflow bug]

Answer (score 4):

This has now been fixed.

As Ilmari Karonen suggested in the other answer, I've updated the CSS so images in the "open source" section of your profile have a max-width of 100%.

Answer (score 2):

An even better generic fix would be:

```css
.markdown img { max-width: 100% }
```

This will scale *any* images in user-supplied Markdown content down to the width of the enclosing element, incidentally also avoiding issues with [images nested insides lists / blockquotes / etc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143973/images-can-be-pushed-outside-the-boundaries-of-a-post-by-using-nested-lists)

(Ps. I could easily add this fix into [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), but I'm not sure it's a good idea; someone using it could end up adding an image to their profile that would look horrible to any prospective employers viewing the profile without SOUP.  Thus, alas, this is probably something that needs to be fixed on SE's side.)