# Background section does not scale background

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs

I've added my Background, but it's overflowed the region:

[image]

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of the background section! It's not meant to be an image, its intended use is to describe your personal background... Tongue in cheek?

Comment: @DeanWard Perhaps just a little :-P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough background information to determine if backgrounds were meant or if backgrounds are the problem all along.

Comment: @Bart Since image tags are supported in this section (and I can think of non-jokey reasons you might want to put one there), I still think this is a valid bug.

Comment: Enough background for me @fredley. Retracted.

Comment: Seems like another instance of [this (fixed) bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232405/images-in-open-source-roles-section-can-overflow-container).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and the Developer Story as of March 31, 2022.  This bug report is now (sadly) moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out! We've added this to our backlog and will get a fix out soon.